# Count number of dataframe column values that satisfy a vector condition

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe column, a, containing rows of numbers:

> df$a
>
> 1 3 5

And a vector, v1, containing a list of numbers:

> v1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

And I want to calculate the number of values in df$a that are greater than each number in v1 such that I get another column, df$b, that looks like this:

> df$b
>
> 9 7 5

Since the conditions need to apply to each row rather than to one specific value, I don't seem to just be able to use which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be

```
df$b <- rowSums(outer(df$a, v1, `<`))
```